# Is there anyway to execute JavaScript from a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot that executes syntax that we give in the server and send the console logs... How can I do that?

Comment: eval(textVar) but that's dangerous.. that's an instant hack of your computer

Comment: I understand that.. but i wanted to test.. thanks tho

Comment: well test at your own risk.. if ur bot is accessible to anyone other than u.. ur basically hacked

Comment: If you restrict the eval to only execute certain commands or for only certain people to use you will be fine. Many bots have direct eval commands. I'd recommend doing some research to ensure you safegaurd an eval command

Answer (score 1):

With [eval("your variable here having script")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function.

Also be careful while using eval().

Comment: one can never be careful enough though kek.. he needs to find a way to do what he wants differently(unless he's building a backdoor and having some hack my box event)

Comment: Only i can use this command..